Nifi in docker with configuration in volume
I am trying to persist configuration for nifi 2.0 container. My docker compose file is something like:
services:
  nifi:
    image: apache/nifi:latest
    container_name: nifi
    ports:
      - "443:8443"
    environment:
      - NIFI_WEB_HTTPS_PORT=8443
      - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_USERNAME=admin
      - SINGLE_USER_CREDENTIALS_PASSWORD=S3curePa55word
      - NIFI_SENSITIVE_PROPS_KEY=pUaEVgyGKT61fMCAWNbjJPMwAcQDuDj4
    volumes:
      - ./nifi/data:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/data
      - ./nifi/logs:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/logs
      - ./nifi/conf:/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf  
    networks:
      - nifi-net
    restart: always

Unfortunately it does not work as initially my ./nifi/conf is empty and nifi does not start. Is it possible to solve it somehow? When I do not use volume mapping for conf, it starts because it uses default values. I wanted to solve problem using some init container technique and copy cfg when not persised, but I am new to docker compose and unable to put it work. Another approach I tried is to use entry section but without success. Can somebody help or suggest some solution?
UPDATE:
I found description of the similar problem in https://medium.com/geekculture/host-a-fully-persisted-apache-nifi-service-with-docker-ffaa6a5f54a3 . Unfortunately there is no solution for this problem as they only suggest:

Start NiFi’s docker container without mounting the conf directory.
Copy the conf directory out of the running container to a local conf directory.
Stop the docker container.
Mount the local conf directory
and restart the docker container.

There has to be some better solution using docker compose I hope.
